# Django + Pymongo creating account confirmation link

Tags: django, mongodb, authentication, token, pymongo

I am building a user module from scratch where users can do pretty much all regular user operations from login,signup,..., to account deactivation. The thing is that I am not using mongoengine or django ready-made models that simplify sql connections, instead I am doing everything from scratch using pymongo driver to connect to mongodb database where I need to code all CRUD operations. I am stuck at creating a temporary link for users to (1) confirm account - this link should not be expired, (2) reset password, this link expires in few days. I have two questions regarding this:

1- can i still use django token generator/ authentication library? I am not using Users django library so my users are just ones I create and insert to database, if yes how can i do that?!

2- if no, how can I generate those temp links considering similar level of security that django library adopts, i.e. hashed username/ salted.. etc.

any advice if I am doing something wrong or I should re-do everything considering mongoengine as my driver so that I can inherit and use django models?! any recommendation is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to extend the existing User Model.
Seems easier, faster and more secure than doing everything on your own.

Here is a good source for your options.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, I have already started the tutorial from the beginning, here is the link for any one interested

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html

Comment: the problem with user module and other classes is that I made a wrong decision of choosing nosql as my database, which does not come handy with django as there is no official support for  it. Every time I overcome an issue i run into another, I think I should reconsider my choice, I will appreciate any recommendation!